# Кусок кода после логотипа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Появился кусок кода после логотипа:

```
docsHero.RenderPartial(Html); storyHero.RenderPartial(Html);
```

Распространяется как на ru.stackoverflow.com, так и ru.meta.stackoverflow.com

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая штука отображается только на страницах списков вопросов, при переходе в любой вопрос - пропадает.

Comment: Ничего подобного не наблюдаю. Можете ссылку на страницу с проблемой добавить?

Comment: Есть репорт об этом же на Мета-Мете, случай явно не единичный: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293434/318749

Comment: @D-side и при этом уже исправленный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё одна причина, доказывающая, что [копи-паста](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293434/possible-scripting-error-on-all-main-se-front-pages#comment953837_293434) - зло:

> Yeah, copy/paste fail when refactoring some view logic, and that only shows up some of the time :/ Pushing a fix in a moment.

Сейчас проблема уже решена.